# Can't get modal JQuery window to update changes to database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

I've spent all day on this issue, and I'm stumped.
I have a web page called "singlecards.aspx", which contains a GridView control that populates from a database, and it works fine.  Here's the code for that file:

**SingleCard.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="SRN - Edit Single Card Records" Language="C#"   MasterPageFile="~/TVS_Main.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SingleCards.aspx.cs" Inherits="Accounts_TVS_SingleCards" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="serverHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script language="text/javascript">
        function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
            document.Form1.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
            document.Form1.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
            document.Form1.submit();
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.popup').live('click', function (e) {

            var page = $(this).attr("href")

            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border:0px; " src = "' + page + '" width=600px" height="100%"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 550,
                width: 'auto',
                title: "Message Details",
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () { $dialog.dialog('close'); }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    __doPostPack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>', '');
                }
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ctMain" runat="server">
    <h1>Manage Single Card Definitions</h1>
    <br />
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <img src="../../images/loading.gif" alt="" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlCards" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="spantwo">
                <h2>Currently Defined Card Records</h2>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objCards" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
                    MaximumRowsParameterName="maxRows" EnablePaging="true" SortParameterName="orderBy"
                    SelectCountMethod="GetCount" SelectMethod="GetList" StartRowIndexParameterName="startRow"
                    TypeName="SRN.Data.SingleCardDB" DataObjectTypeName="SRN.Data.SingleCard"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvCards" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="CardID" PageSize="10"
                    DataSourceID="objCards" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid"
                    ToolTip="Definitions of Single Tarot Cards"
                    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true" OnRowCommand="gvCards_RowCommand">
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_header"></HeaderStyle>
                    <RowStyle CssClass="grid_rowstyle"></RowStyle>
                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="grid_selectedrowstlye"></SelectedRowStyle>
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grid_alternatingrowstyle"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <center>
                        <span class="darkred">No data to display at this time.</span>       
                    </center>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CardName" HeaderText="Card Name" SortExpression="CardName" />
                        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="IsActive"
                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a class="popup" href='editsinglecard.aspx?CardID=<%# Eval("CardID") %>'>Edit</a>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="EditMeanings" Text="Meanings" ControlStyle-CssClass="gridbutton"
                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:ButtonField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <p></p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh Records" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" CssClass="button"></asp:Button>
                <br />
                [<a class="popup" href="editsinglecard.aspx">Add New Card</a>]
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <p></p>
    <div class="dataentry">
        <div class="spantwo">
            [<a class="button" href="clienthome.aspx" title="Return To Main Page">Back To Main Page</a>]
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The page displays a GridView of database records.  One of the fields is a template field with a link that calls the JQuery script to open a popup window to display a record for editing.  The code for that page, EditSingleCard.aspx, is here (.aspx file first then the code-behind):

**EditSingleCard.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EditSingleCard.aspx.cs" Inherits="Accounts_TVS_EditSingleCard" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Edit Card Definition</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../styles/tarotverbatim_main.css" />
</head>
<body class="body_whiteBG">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updCard" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h2>Add/Edit Card Definition</h2>
            <br />
            <table class="table_small">
                <tr>
                    <td class="table_td_leftcol">
                        <span class="formlabel">Card Name :</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_td_rightcol">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbCardName" runat="server" Width="95%" MaxLength="64"
                            ToolTip="Name you wish to use as an internal reference"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfCardName" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="tbCardName" CssClass="darkred" Text="*"
                            ErrorMessage="'Card Name' is required.">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="table_td_leftcol">
                        <span class="formlabel">Name Seen By Users:</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_td_rightcol">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbConsumerTitle" runat="server" Width="95%" MaxLength="64"
                            ToolTip="What will the users see as this card's name?"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfConsumerTitle" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="tbConsumerTitle" CssClass="darkred" Text="*"
                            ErrorMessage="'Consumer Title' is required.">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="table_td_leftcol">
                        <span class="formlabel">Card Image File :</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_td_rightcol">
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="ctlImage" runat="server" AllowMultiple="false"
                            ToolTip="Image file to associate with this card"></asp:FileUpload>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="table_td_leftcol">
                        <span class="formlabel">Is Record Active? :</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_td_rightcol">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="table_td_spantwo">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="button"
                            Text="Save/Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"></asp:Button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="button"
                            Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="table_td_spantwo">
                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsCard" runat="server"
                            CssClass="darkred"
                            HeaderText="Please correct the following :"></asp:ValidationSummary>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
          <br />
          <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code-behind is this:

**EditSingleCard.aspx.cs**

```
   using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SRN.Data;
using SRN.Web;
using System.IO;
using SRN.IO;

public partial class Accounts_TVS_EditSingleCard : SRN.Web.SRNBasePage
{
    static string cardID;
    static SingleCard card;
    static bool isNew;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ClearFields();
        }
        LoadCardInfo();
    }


    void LoadCardInfo()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["CardID"] == "")
        {
            isNew = true;
            return;
        }
        cardID = Request.QueryString["CardID"];
        card = SingleCardDB.Get(cardID);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(card.CardID.ToString()))
        {
            isNew = false;
            tbCardName.Text = card.CardName;
            tbConsumerTitle.Text = card.ConsumerTitle;
        }
    }

    void ClearFields()
    {
        tbCardName.Text = "";
        tbConsumerTitle.Text = "";
        lblStatus.Text = "";
        chkActive.Checked = true;
        card = new SingleCard();
    }


    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            if (isNew && !ctlImage.HasFile)
            {
                lblStatus.CssClass = "darkred";
                lblStatus.Text = "You must select an image file to associate with this card.";
                return;
            }
            card.CardImageFile = (!isNew ? "N/A" : ctlImage.FileName.ToString());
            if (card.CardID.Length == 0)
                card.CardID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            card.CardName = Helpers.ProperCase(tbCardName.Text);
            card.ConsumerTitle = tbConsumerTitle.Text;
            card.IsActive = chkActive.Checked;
            bool success = SingleCardDB.Add(card);
            if (success)
            {
                PostImage();
                isNew = false;
                cardID = card.CardID;
                lblStatus.CssClass = "darkgreen";
                lblStatus.Text = "Record saved successfully.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.CssClass = "darkred";
                lblStatus.Text = "Unable to post record at this time.";
            }
        }
    }


    void PostImage()
    {
        if (ctlImage.HasFile)
        {
            string imageURL = Helpers.ApplicationPath + "accounts/tvs/ImageBank/" + ctlImage.PostedFile.FileName;
            ctlImage.SaveAs(imageURL);
        }
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearFields();
    }
}
```

So my problem is this: The popup window comes up just fine, displaying the record selected from the GridView, and the edit *seems* to go just fine.  However, for some reason, the changes I make to the form fields don't take.  When I run the debugger and put in breakpoints to inspect the values in the form fields, they're still the original values, not the new ones. I don't get it!
I use this same form to add new records to the database (click the "Add New Card" link on the SingleCards.aspx page and it comes up fine) and it works to add.  Just not to update.
I could really use some help understanding this.

SECOND question...In the SingleCards.aspx page, you see a button called "btnRefresh" which, naturally, reloads the GridView control.  As part of the modal window close code in the JQuery code of the page, the "Click" event of that button should be called to refresh the gridview when the user closes the modal window, but it doesn't.  Any pointers as to why?
Thanks a million, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding the behavior thoroughly I am modifying my answer as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ClearFields();
            LoadCardInfo();

        }
    }
```

The first thing that gets executed on post back is the Page_Load  event, which in this case reloaded the old form values. Moving `LoadCardInfo()` into  `(!Page.IsPostBack)`     should eliminate the described behaivior.

In addition for the refresh not working
Try:
....

```
close: function Refresh() {
var RefreshButton = $('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>');
RefreshButton.click();
}
```

..and try to step through that code and or put up some `alert()` to see if the event gets triggered

Comment: I will try your suggestion about the refresh button, which is appreciated,but it has nothing to do with why the modal form won't post.

Comment: In fact, when I step through the update button code of the modal form, the fields still show original values. When I click the update button, I noticed that the form resets it's fields to original values, but only when editing an existing record, not when adding a new one. This is weird!

Comment: ".....and the edit seems to go just fine" that seems to indicate that the data gets updated in your DataStore: SingleCardDB). So the problem seemed to be that the new values were not updating to the original form. I was assuming that all your DAL is working properly.
Now that I read carefully it seems like you don't have any Update code defined. just Add

Comment: The DAL works OK. The problem is on the post. I noticed that the form fields reset to original values when I click the update button. The new values don't post. Any thoughts?

Comment: youu have: 
if (isNew && !ctlImage.HasFile) which seems to indicate that it is only meant for adding a new (Card) - > as in:   bool success = SingleCardDB.Add(card); which presumably add a new record But does it also handle edits?

Comment: That's to ensure the user includes an image when adding a new record.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the code. When the form loads, there's a test to see if a record I'd was passed in as part of the querystring. If not, or if the record doesn't exist, the isNew flag is set to true. If it's a new record then the user has to include a new image file in the file upload control.

Comment: what happens when it's  "isNew" = false?

Comment: The user is told to add an image and the method aborts gracefully.

Comment: OK, what I am trying to draw your attention to is::   It looks as if your code only is able to add:   SingleCardDB.Add() 
Since I cant see that code I cant tell for certain but there doesn't seem to be a way to differentiate between a new and or an existing record (Card)

Comment: The "Add" method of the DAL class calls a stored proc that handles either new or existing records. The issue, when I step through the code as it runs, is that the form values themselves are still showing as original values, not the new ones. For whatever reason, when I click the update button, the form fields reset to old values. That's the problem. The DAL works fine - it is receiving bad data from the form.

Comment: Maybe because your card declaration is static and you are not instantiating a new SingleCard object in you btnUpdate_Click method

Comment: The issue is not the DAL or the static invocation of the SingleCard class.  The problem is that when I run the site in debug and look at the form values returned when the user clicks the update  button, they are the original values of the record, not the new ones.  And the form itself changes to reflect the original values as soon as the update button is clicked.  So that's where the problem is.  I know the DAL is good, otherwise adding a new record would fail too, but it doesn't.

Comment: In that case, then it sounds like your form is performing the post back and (reloads the fields) in you page_onload event. 
Even a partial post back will trigger page_onload  (LoadCardInfo();
) which in your case wipes out the fields before it get to the  btnUpdate_Click handler.
Step through the code beginning in the page onload and you'll see what I mean. 
You should move the LoadCardInfo() into the !ispostback  condition

Comment: See?  That's why I needed another set of eyes to look at it! (chuckle)  The LoadCardInfo() was in the wrong place (should have been inside the postback test), so it was firing on the form postback.  WHEW!!!  You're a lifesaver there, DaniDev!  If I can figure out why the refresh doesn't fire when the modal form closes, I'll be in great shape!

Comment: Glad we were able to finally get to the root of the problem. I think it too a thorough description of the behavior to solve the issue. I will modify my answer so that you can accept it.
As far as getting the refresh to work, did you try modifying to click() as I suggested, if so try to step through that code and or put up some alerts to see if the event gets triggered.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no luck, so today will be a quest to solve it. Thanks for your help with the update part. That was my stupidity!

Comment: Try to step through the close: and put up some alerts

BTW, (suggestion) the title of your question is misleading as it seems like you have ascertained that DB update is failing which is what I thought the problem was, rather than the fields reverting to old values.

Comment: so, any luck triggering the refresh button?

Comment: Nope, and I can't track down why. Frustrated.

Comment: what happens when you do:
close: function Refresh() {
alert( $('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>'))

}

Comment: It pops up a dialog box that says "object Object"

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the button's cli CT event, and it isn't being triggered.

Comment: Good News: The fact that you got that message says your code is generally OK otherwise and that it is trying to do what you want.
Bad News: your btnRefresh.ClientID may not be locateable . it may be in a disabled state? You are on the right track don' give up try to look up jquery info site.   
also it be nice if you acknowledged the help I've provided you in standard SO  manner ;-)

Comment: Also:
You might changing your refresh button to a regular http button witch then call a simple refresh javascript (if youre not doing anything fancy on your btnRefresh_Click  function. This will simply things for you and things will be that much more transparent.
asp button are notoriously hard to control with Javascript

Comment: The only point of the refresh button was to have a target to invoke a databind call to reload the gridview when the modal window closed.

Comment: understood. Well, if you can't locate your asp.button or get it to click then you might want to use AjaxControlToolkit  modal popup.
I use it about half the time. It's got issues but it'll work well for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing this differently.  I also tried something very similar.  The frustration with full postbacks, startup scripts, and dialogs -- it was never ending.  An alternative approach:

Bind the data to the grid view as you have.
In the RowDataBound event in the GridView (on the CS side) add an onclick event handler.  Pass the ID of the record which you are trying to update.
On the JS side, when this handler is fired, popup a JQ modal dialog.
Block the modal dialog with BlockUI. 
Use a page method / web service to go get the data
When the data is retrieved, unblock the dialog. 
Update the database and grid when a button is clicked on the dialog.  Refreshing the grid can be tricky since the orders of the records may change - I wrote a webservice that replaces one row of the table and I do that manually.

This runs quicker, and appears to run almost instantaneously, since the dialog comes up almost instantly.  Most importantly, you don't have to deal with the "events" on the CS side, update panels, etc. It means you'll have to get your hands dirty with the JS.   In the end, tho, it'll perform better and there won't be any "black box" where things happen that you don't have any visibility into.